# how to copy ssh key from client server to linux desktop using scp

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp, ssh-agent

I want to copy ssh key `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` from client-server to Linux desktop folder.
I already test it `scp command` for a copy from Linux server to client-server

`scp id_rsa.pub username@client_ip:/path_name`

But it doesn't work on server to linux desktop.

Comment: what error do you get? do you have SSH server running on your desktop machine? SCP will only work if SSH service is running on the target host.

Comment: Connection timed out
lost connection

Comment: I use scp already copy from local to server its works fine . but in server to local problem!

Comment: as per my comment, do you have SSH running on the local machine and ports opened both on the PC and your router?

Comment: Note that the source file for scp can be remote, i.e. you can do `scp user@server:/path/to/file /local/path` on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scp copy to work on the opposite direction, you'd have to have sshd (SSH Service Deamon) running on your desktop. Also, the desktop IP and SSH port (22 by default) must be accessible by the server, and this is not the case on most internet connections nowadays (because you usually are behind a NAT and your desktop is not accessible from the internet without an explicit network configuration -- such as a firewall rule or a port forwarding)

That being said, if you just want to quickly copy the files and it is already working on one direction, you may want to keep the direction of the connection (desktop to server) but invert the direction of the copy itself.

That would be easily achieved by inverting the arguments of scp, in your example:

Running command on the desktop, copying local **to** server:

`scp id_rsa.pub username@server_ip:/path_name`

Still running command on the desktop, but copying **from** server to local:

`scp username@server_ip:/path_name/id_rsa.pub .`

Comment: I use the second one and it returns: `usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`

Comment: @Sabbir the message says your usage is wrong, you missed the final dot perhaps? please paste the complete command you are using (you may change the ip to an invalid one for privacy reasons)

Comment: @Sabbir did it work?

Comment: yes, brother, it works. @fabiano

Comment: @Sabbir Great! Would you please then mark the answer as accepted so the question doesn't keep showing as unanswered?